# Didn't the lottery of Achan make G-d an informant?

Tags: maseches-sanhedrin, joshua--book-of, cherem, mesirah

In [Sanhedrin 43b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.43b.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) God says he will not tell Yehoshua who took of the *cherem* of Yericho because God is not an informer

> אמר לפניו רבש"ע מי חטא אמר ליה וכי דילטור אני
>
> Joshua said to G-d: Master of the Universe, who is the one who has sinned? God said to him: Am I an informer [deilator]?

So in order to ascertain who the sinner is [Yehoshua makes use of a lottery](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0607.htm#14). However it would seem to me that this does not solve the God-as-informer problem. If the veracity of the lots is assumed because the outcome is guided by God then God is essentially still an informant (albeit without explicitly 'saying' who did it). If the outcome is pure chance then Achan's retort is correct and the lots are random and have no true meaning.

How can we understand why the use of lots does not constitute God being an informant?

Comment: The lots on Yonah's ship worked almost exactly the same way

Comment: Probably you base it on the Posuk (Mishle 17, 33): "בַּחֵיק יוּטַל אֶת־הַגּוֹרָל וּמֵיְהוָה כָּל־מִשְׁפָּטוֹ׃" Lots are cast into the lap; The decision depends on the LORD. Maybe you should include this in the question, and that will stress the point.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's why I decided to retract my comment.

Comment: @Al_Berko That's Prov. 16:33 not 17:, http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2816.htm

Answer (score 8):

This is an excellent question, and is asked in many places such as [here](http://www.levladaat.org/data/upl/tihon/shmuel4.pdf), [here](https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=39684), [here](https://mikyab.net/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%99-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%99%E2%80%8E/), [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Tzadik%2C_Shushan_Purim.2.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and many other places.  By far the best set of answers are found in the second link above, from Daf-yomi.com, with my rough summary below:

> א. דבר ה' ליהושע היה בגילוי נבואה, והיא מדרגה עליונה של דבקות בקדושה. רק על גילוי נבואה נאמר שאין בו פחיתות ערך של דילטורין. אבל באופנים אחרים – כשם שה' מַגְבִּיהִי לָשָׁבֶת (תהלים קיג, ה) כך הוא גם מַשְׁפִּילִי לִרְאוֹת (שם ו).‏
>
> ב. אמרו במסכת סנהדרין דף מג ע"ב:
>   "אמר לפניו: רבונו של עולם, מי חטא? אמר ליה: וכי דילטור אני? לך הפל גורלות. הלך והפיל גורלות, ונפל הגורל על עכן, אמר לו: יהושע, בגורל אתה בא עלי?! אתה ואלעזר הכהן שני גדולי הדור אתם, אם אני מפיל עליכם גורל - על אחד מכם הוא נופל. אמר לו: בבקשה ממך... מיד: ויען עכן את יהושע ויאמר אמנה אנכי חטאתי לה' אלהי ישראל וכזאת וכזאת עשיתי".
>   כפי שטען עכן, גם בגורל אין בכדי להוכיח ולהצביע על החוטא. תועלת הגורל היתה בכך שהוא שגרם לעכן להודות בעצמו על חטאו.‏
>
> ג. דילטור הוא ההולך רכיל, כפירוש רש"י, ודרך לשון הרע להאמר בלחש ככתוב בקהלת י, יא: אִם יִשֹּׁךְ הַנָּחָשׁ בְּלוֹא לָחַשׁ וְאֵין יִתְרוֹן לְבַעַל הַלָּשׁוֹן. וכוונת ה' היתה שאין מן הראוי שיאשים יהושע את עכן בטענה כי מה' נלחש לו מאחורי גבו. ואילו עדות הגורל היא בפני עיני הכל.‏

Answer 1 - there is a difference between being a slanderer through Nevuah, a very holy method of communication between man and G-d. Only through this method would there be an issue of telling Lashon Hara, but not through a more natural method of communicating, such as a lottery.

Answer 2 - Indeed, Achan is correct in noting that a lottery does not conclusively prove anything. However, the purpose of the lottery was to put him in the spotlight and cause him to admit. (See [here](https://www.google.ca/search?client=opera&q=on%20the%20head%20of%20the%20theif%2C%20the%20hat%20burns&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) as well.) Indeed, Yehoshua even asks him to admit, which is emphasized by the very Gemara you are asking about.

Answer 3 - We see indications from many places that it is inappropriate to convict people from informers, who secretly tell Lashon Hara about people behind their backs. Therefore, here, Hashem desired that the lottery be done in front of the entire nation, to avoid being a private informer (this may work well with the language of the Gemara "וכי דילטור אני **לך**"?)