# (How) was Joshua allowed to trick Achan?

Tags: capital-punishment, maseches-sanhedrin, sheker-false, joshua--book-of, yehoshua-joshua

In [Sanhedrin 43b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.43b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it says that Joshua tells Achan that if he confesses he will be pardoned (והיפטר). Rashi explains that Joshua verbally deceived Achan into confessing, making Achan think he would not be killed. How was Joshua allowed to do this?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104503/15256

Comment: It probably refers to Olam Haba, should he admit his guilt.

Comment: @DanielRoss As the question says, Rashi explains it to mean that he was made to think that he wouldn't be killed